Crystal Report - Duplicated detail lines when the sub-report in the group footer has multiple lines
Main report group is based on Contract.  Detail section contains contract line items.  The sub-report is placed in the group footer (linked by contract).  If the sub-report has 3 lines of data, the detail line items are repeated 3 times.  I need help please.
I want the detail lines to print once, not once per line of the sub-report.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
